# How can I update an entry in a HashMap with a refrence to a key?

Tags: performance, rust

I am writing a function which may insert or update a value into a HashMap that is part of a structure.
My map is of type `HashMap<String, Value>` where `Value` is an enum defined elsewhere in my program. I have a function `pub fn bind(&mut self, name: &str, value: Value)` on my structure, that inserts or updates an entry in the HashMap, currently my code looks like this:

```rs
pub fn bind(&mut self, name: &str, value: Value) -> /* snip */ {
        /* snip */

        self.bindings.insert(name.to_string(), value);

        /* snip */    
}
```

This is fine if `name` was not already in the hashmap, but if it was, would it be possible to avoid the overhead of to_string by updating the existing entry, instead of calling to_string and allocating more memory for a string that we already have? I'm looking to do something like this:

```rs
pub fn bind(&mut self, name: &str, value: Value) -> /* snip */ {
        /* snip */

        if (self.bindings.contains(name)) {
                // this update method does not exist
                self.bindings.update(name, value);
        } else {
                self.bindings.insert(name.to_string(), value);
        }        
        
        /* snip */    
}
```

Comment: With the current API, you're basically trading between having to allocate a clone, and having to recompute the hash multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`HashMap::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get_mut) to get a reference to the value if it exists, which allows you to modify it - in particular by assigning a new value.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3844f81b3640d97894511ae5a79dfa30)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, improved performance by 10-15% in my benchmark case so this definitely beats just calling `to_string` every time

Comment: @Rafael also take a look at the [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) which can lead to cleaner code.

Comment: @egerhard Unfortunately in this case the entry API won't help the OP, as it unconditionally requires an owned key, which is what the OP wanted to avoid.